# I tried to run streamlit app in command prompt but it gives Fatal error

Tags: python, streamlit

I tried to run my `streamlit` script in the command prompt for deployment in the app.py file location

```
C:\Users\HP\IRIS>streamlit run app.py
```

but it gives, Fatal error in the launcher:

```
Unable to create process using '"c:\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Python39\Scripts\streamlit.exe" run app.py': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

And pip and Python are also in the current version, and I tried to set up the system environment also.
How can I solve this error to run streamlit app.py in my command prompt?

Please help me, and I advance thank you to give all your solutions.

I tried to run streamlit app in the command prompt but it gives a fatal error.
I'm using

```
Python 3.11.3 version
and pip 23.1.2 version
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls` or `dir` (depending upon what terminal you are using)?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are in the directory that holds the file *app.py*, this should work indeed.

Did you check if *streamlit.exe* is indeed in C:\Python39\Scripts\ ?

Also, for good measures, can you confirm if you have the following in your system PATH ? :

> C:\Python39
> C:\Python39\Scripts\

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, In C:\Python39\Scripts it has streamlit.exe file but still it gives error.